# How to import products from OpenCart 1.5.6.4 in OpenCart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, upgrade, opencart2.x

I have exported my products in an Excel spreadsheet file, and I then installed my products in a clean installation of OpenCart 1.5.6.4. Then I uploaded OpenCart 2.0.3.1 and ran the Upgrade script. The first time I ran the script, it went well even though it added some new lines in my config.php files.

Is there a way to export my products and categories, from my OpenCart 1.5.6.4 and import them directly in a OpenCart 2.0.3.1 installation?

I have some upgrading script in the extension store, but nothing worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCart 1.5.6.4, go to menu Admin -> System -> Backup/Restore and select all product tables and take backup of it. In OpenCart 2.0.3.1, goto menu Admin -> Tools -> Backup / Restore and there upload your backup file and do restore. That's it.

Before restoring a database, I would recommend to first take a backup of all tables in the current version you are restoring. Also you should take care about some fields added in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can export your opencart 1.5.6 products,Categories,Attribute and import them to your opencart 2.2.x by [this](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17) extension. For Opencart 1.5.6 install the extension of this version and then import them through this extension.

Answer (score 0):

If your OC 1.5.6.4 was not a living system, basicly you can do it with suggested ways and you'll be fine. If it was , you  need to export them with related living tables (order,address, customer, customer ip,order history, order_product, order_total etc). Pls first backup!. Always backup regularly. Truncate target tables(they may have demo data)   , switch off their autoincrement properties if they have. (after migrating you will need to switch on again.(always note, dont trust your memory) , check existing of any different fields between two tables structure and arrange them (not much but there are) and finally code some "insert into select from"  sql statements , thats all. Remaining stuff will be some tests and minor corrections. I prefered this manuel way and migrated from a living OC 1.5.5.1 to 3.0.3.1. Was fun indeed. Honestly didnt try other ways. Maybe they were more easy than this. But the advantage of this way is helping you to progress oc know-how.Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's a detailed job, if you use Excel you can save time and bring the data correctly between versions, if you have many products divide it into several spreadsheets so as not to overload the server.
See that you need to import first, if there are options, filters and attributes.
I hope it helps.